authentication error during discord api patch request
I am using zapier to send a single image to a message , to append this image, I am getting an error of 401: Unauthorized (HTTP Status Code: 401) , I am sending my bot token and I have authorized the bot I created for this from discord developer portal to access that link, although I am sure I am using the wrong link , as it does not make sense to have a auth link to append an image to a single message, but I am not sure what link to use, or what the auth issue is. thanks.
my url to send the patch request to : https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/1243353599866699888/messages/1246209371331891312
data being sent as json :
{
  "embeds": [
    {
      "image": {
        "url": {{_GEN_1717086889359__tasks[]result__files[]url}}
      }
    }
  ]
}


I used the following headers :
"Content-Type": "application/json"
"Authorization" : "Bot <secret bot token #>"
i successfully added the bot to my discord and it has admin privleges for the time being at least, but maybe because I don't understand what the endpoint should really be? I'm not sure what else the problem could be.
